# How to set the drag area in qml windowless application

Tags: c++, qt, qml

my question is how can i set to drag the app without window-decorations
i have seen so many apps which are drag-able through desktop with mouse. my app uses Qml so any possible way do get this work thanks .

Comment: Why is there a `unity` tag on this question? Are you sure you're using the right tag?

Comment: sorry am new here , my application is for ubuntu which uses unity as D.E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your `MouseArea::positionChanged` signal and use the position delta (you'll have to save the last position on each call so you can calculate the delta) to update your `Window::x` and `y` properties.

```
Window {
    id: win
    width: 200
    height: 200

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        property int lastX
        property int lastY

        onPositionChanged: {
            // Remap the mouse coords back to the window.  Not
            // necessary in this example, but will be in 'real'
            // use.
            var mPos = mapToItem( null, mouse.x, mouse.y );
            mPos.x += win.x;
            mPos.y += win.y;

            // Skip the first iteration by testing if the properties
            // are defined, otherwise the window will jump.
            if ( lastX && lastY ) {
                win.x += mPos.x - lastX;
                win.y += mPos.y - lastY;
            }

            lastX = mPos.x;
            lastY = mPos.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked like charm thanks  a lot man :) unfortunately i cant give a +1 but i accepted your answer as it solved my problem :) thanks once again